# Unusual function behavior - returns different results for same variable?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list as part of a game I'm working on. Let's say:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I also have a function:

```
def my_function(my_list):
    a = [x for x in my_list if x < 4]
    b = [x for x in my_list if x < 4] ## exactly the same as for `a`
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

The result of calling `my_function(my_list)` is:

`a` prints as it should:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

But `b` prints an empty list:

```
[]
```

Obviously the code above is just an example (it would be highly impractical for me to copy my whole code), but it's pretty much a copy of the issue I'm facing in my code. Does anyone know what could be causing such behavior?

Comment: Have you checked if `my_list` is being modified after the `a` assignment for some reason?

Comment: Right before your `a = ` line, add `print(type(my_list), repr(my_list))`.. it's quite likely it's not actually a list at all, but some iterable which is being exhausted..

Comment: Can't reproduce this via a quick test on my Android Python interpreter.

Comment: You seem to be right, it's not a list: `<class 'generator'>`. Thank you, this gives me something to look into. EDIT: problem solved. Thanks again, feel free to post a separate message so I can pick it as the best answer.